# His boss gave him a talking to

Tags: prepositions

The customer service representative spoke impatiently to a customer. Afterwards:

> His boss gave him *a talking to*.  [told him he had performed unacceptably]

Is **to** to be considered a part of the noun?

Comment: There are usages like *Let's give him a hearing* (listen to what he has to say) or *Have a listen to this song* where a preposition simply doesn't work syntactically. And others such as *They gave me a going-over* (they beat me up) that wouldn't even have any *meaning* without the preposition. But your example fits somewhere in the middle, in that it still makes sense and seems "grammatical" without the preposition, but hyphenated ***talking-to*** is the idiomatically established preference (as an alternative to *The boss had a talk with him*, with no preposition).

Comment: I don't recall ever hearing it in an American accent, but in colloquial BrE we have *They gave him a good seeing-to* (roughed him up, gave him a going-over). For some reason, *seeing-to* is nearly always preceded by an adjectival "intensifier" *(good, right, proper, thorough)*, but I think this feature is less pronounced with *going-over*.

Comment: I feel this question may stand a chance of getting better answers on [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/), past that of dictionary definitions (although I hope to be proved wrong!).

Answer (score 1):

It's an idiom "[give a talking to](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/give+a+talking+to)" = a lengthy rebuke, to scold or reprimand. "**to**" is a part of that idiom but without a hyphen in their example:

- Dad gave us both a good **talking to**

> Considered colloquial; second half of 1800s.

It's also a noun. [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/talking-to) definitions for "**a talking-to**":

- an angry or serious conversation in which you criticize someone's behavior
- an often wordy scolding

Comment: It was his third talking-to that week.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.

> **talking-to** *noun (informal)*
>   A sharp reprimand in which someone is told that they have done wrong.
>   ‘they gave Peter a talking-to about solving problems with words, not fists’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/talking-to)